Spring oauth2login with netty embedded server
I am using spring boot 3 reactive stack.
Netty server.
I am trying to make a login with idp with the help of oauth2login (oaut2client library).
The calls are stack, I believe due to proxy issue.
As I understand webclient does not take the proxy settings from the VM.
I tried to provide custom proxied client without luck.
How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
